# wordpress sort search results by date 

Tags: php, wordpress, search, sorting, resultset

Is there any special parameter that i can pass to search url to sort it by date .
And is there any parameter to increase the number of search results returned ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example search URL?

Comment: ah okay one param i know that give you rss of results is = http://blog.vtravelled.com/?s=how&feed=rss2 = "fee=rss2" .I wana know if there are more options i can pass with search url to sort and increase returned items.

Comment: or a link to some wordpress codex page explaining this would be more than helpfull :P

Answer (score 1):

WordPress search is already sorted by date, most recent first.  If that's not what you're looking for, you're out of luck without using plugins and/or editing source code.  So no, (taking a guess here) you can't pass URL parameters to a search on a 3rd party WordPress site to change the info you get back.

This quote from Joost de Valk, one of the leading WordPress gurus out there, from his site [yoast.com](http://yoast.com/wordpress-search/)

> WordPress default search kinda sucks. It sorts the results by date, newest first, and interface wise it doesn't have any of the cool things we're used to when we search in for instance Google.

That article is mainly on how to improve the search functionality of your own site.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some modifications on the [Search Unleashed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-unleashed/) plugin, it's the best one I've found and is pretty customizable

Answer (score 0):

I believe this plugin will allow you to sort by date: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nop no plugins , It must be applicable for any wordpress blog search.

Comment: The main purpose is to use it on any third party wordpress blog.